# Error on gpg key exported from linux to Mac

Tags: mac, encryption

I have exported a gpg key from linux to Mac. Exporting commands on linux are as follows

```
gpg --export-secret-keys -a test_01.asc
gpg --export -a test_01_pub.asc
```

Importing commands on Mac are as follows

```
gpg --import test_01.asc
gpg --import test_01_pub.asc
```

But when decrypting with the imported key,

```
gpg -d -vvv test_01.gpg
```

gpg said

```
gpg: using character set 'utf-8'
gpg: enabled compatibility flags:
# off=0 ctb=85 tag=1 hlen=3 plen=268
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        data: [2048 bits]
gpg: public key is XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
# off=271 ctb=d2 tag=18 hlen=2 plen=62 new-ctb
:encrypted data packet:
        length: 62
        mdc_method: 2
gpg: using subkey XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX instead of primary key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg: encrypted with rsa2048 key, ID XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, created xxxx-xx-xx
      "xxx <xxx@xxx.com>"
gpg: public key decryption failed: Bad secret key
gpg: decryption failed: Bad secret key
```

And when I tried to change its passwd, gpg said

```
error getting keyinfo from agent: System error w/o errno
pKey has only stub or on-card key items - no passphrase to change.
```

The versions of gpgs on Linux and Mac are 2.2.41 and 2.4.0

Comment: You need to export and import both the private and public keys. How did you do this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added the exporting and importing commands in the description. Are they proper for exporting keys from linux to Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the explaining. The problem has been solved. After regenerating a new dir ~/.gnupg and configing the pinentry-mac for pin entrying, the key importing process prompts for passwd and the key is imported successed.